# PHP domDocument remove element by attribute value

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I want to remove the element for an attribute value which is declared by some variable. I have a xml like this:

```
<configuration name="acl.conf" description="Network Lists">
  <network-lists><!-- IMS ALLOW ONLY -->
    <list name="test" default="deny">
      <node type="allow" cidr="11.11.11.101/32"/>
   </list>
   <list name="customer" default="deny" type="allow">
      <node type="allow" cidr="10.13.13.193/32"/>
      <node type="allow" cidr="10.13.13.194/32"/>
      <node type="allow" cidr="10.13.13.3/32"/>
      <node type="allow" cidr="10.13.13.2/32"/>
   </list>
  </network-lists>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help me with the php code? I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
    <?php
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$doc->load('acl.conf.xml');

$searchNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "node" );

foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode )
{
    $valueID = $searchNode->getAttribute('cidr');

    } 
?>
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: @SahilGulati for example, i want to remove <node type="allow" cidr="10.13.13.2/32"/> . so the output will be <configuration name="acl.conf" description="Network Lists">
  <network-lists><!-- IMS ALLOW ONLY -->
    <list name="test" default="deny">
      <node type="allow" cidr="11.11.11.101/32"/>
   </list>
   <list name="customer" default="deny" type="allow">
      <node type="allow" cidr="10.13.13.193/32"/>
      <node type="allow" cidr="10.13.13.194/32"/>
      <node type="allow" cidr="10.13.13.3/32"/></list>
  </network-lists>
</configuration>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$_GET['id']` is the `cidr` value you want to remove, I'd use XPath

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//node[@cidr="' . $id . '"]')
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Comment: it solved, i used your aswer and it work! Thank you so much